# Can access entire NAS, but can't map it as network drive

Tags: windows-10, networking, nas, samba

I can access my entire NAS via Windows Explorer (Samba), but I cannot map it as network drive. I must always map a particular share:

[image]

Is this a normal situation? Is there anything I can do about it?

I have six folders in my NAS and I'd like to map root of my NAS ("all of them at once") under single drive letter (network drive). My previous router allowed me to do so, but I don't know if this wasn't a flaw in its software.

It seems (if only I am not doing something wrong) that my new router doesn't allow that and that I must map each of my six folders as a separate six network drivers (drive letters). Very, very unhandy as for me.

Comment: That is correct. you cannot connect to a server in the same way you can a share. all you are doing is asking the server to enumerate its shares, which is very different from what happens when you actually connect to a share and work with its contents. Personally, on my linux NAS, I just use `ln -s` or `mount -o` to link folders outside of a share path to a location within the share so my users can access them. but it does have to be a share you connect to, not the server alone.

Comment: That would have been a feature specific to the NAS, as the NAS would have had to do something similar to what @FrankThomas said since Windows doesn't support that

Comment: Thank you. If any of you care to craft an answer out of that comments, I'll delight to accept it.